# Upcoming Ethereum hard fork and ERC-20 token as fiat money

Tags: tokens, erc-20, hardforks

The ethereum network may face a new hard fork with the release of Ethereum 2.0 (scalability fixes)

Is it true that we might have two parallel ethereum networks each running a different consensus mechanism?

What happens with the tokens in that case? If i have 100 tokens before the fork, and later after the fork they are going to be duplicated. Will I be able to spend 200 tokens? 
Let’s think of the token as a fiat currency for example. (1 token = 1$) i don’t mean a crypto currency, but rather like fiat money backed in a real guarantee bank account.

I would really appreciate if anyone could clear this out for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serenity wont be a hardfork persay. It'll be a new network deployed with a link back to the existing mainnet, so the current mainnet as we know it will continue exist and all the tokens that exist on it will continue as they are. None of it will be replicated on the new beacon chain or any of the other shards. The current mainnet will essentially become a shard on the new beacon chain.